# What is the astral universe mentioned here that is different from the universe in conscious dream?

Tags: scripture, body, ayurveda, universe

The universe which we experience with the physical body is the physical universe. The universe experienced by the subtle body is a dream universe (say). The book I am reading mentioned another universe called the astral universe. I don't know any difference between a dream universe and the astral universe.

Consider the following excerpt from a book written by *David Frawley aka Vamadeva Shastri*

> Behind the physical is a subtle or astral body composed of prana,
> emotions and thoughts. The astral is the underlying energy pattern of
> the physical, from which the physical is produced. In our waking life,
> we experience the astral through the physical. **In the dream state, the
> astral body is free to function on its own and we can experience it
> directly through conscious dreaming. There is another plane of
> existence, an astral universe, which we can experience through the
> astral body. Its experience can be developed through yoga and other
> occult techniques.**
>
> [The role of the astral body, II.10 Ayurvedic psychology, Ayurvedic
> Healing](https://archive.org/details/ayurvedichealingacomprehensiveguidedavidfrawleymlbd_832_W/page/317/mode/1up?view=theater)

What is the astral universe mentioned here? Please explain it from the scripture that explains it in detail.

Comment: This topic is seemingly relatable to Sivananda Swami's writings on Meditation

https://www.sivanandaonline.org/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=1392&parent=640&format=html

Esp. the section Various Experiences in Meditation, sub section Feeling of Separation... Scriptures ( like kundalini practices etc)may touch upon it , but the implied meaning should only be experienced as it is indescribable in words.

Comment: Firstly lets clarify astral body != sukshma sharira .Astral body is a concept that predates Christianity and originated in Ancient Greece.So according to Hindu philosophy there exists no "astral" universes.So no references can be found in hindu texts, can assume it as an extremely crude transliteration of *lokas* as at the time of death, atma leaves the physical body along with sukshma sharira and migrates to a higher or a lower loka according to its karma.The translation of sukshma sharira into astral body eliminates the concept of transmigration and stored impressions from past lives.

Comment: The concept of astral body lacks the intellectual  foundation  like  the  Vedas  and  its  relationship  with reincarnation  is  non-existent.  The  astral  body  is  composed  of  finer matter and is said to be surrounded by an aura of flashing colors. It is a medium of transmission between the brain and mind and is able to  move  rapidly  to  great  distances,  making  a  person  capable  of cosmic travel.While  all  living  beings  have  sukshma  sharira,  astral  body  is  limited only to humans.

Comment: Only reference i can think of is what i read in the book Autobiography of a Yogi, when resurrection of Sri Yukteshwar Giri happens and he narrates his experiences of "astral" travel and "planets" to Paramhamsa Yogananda ji....Obvio no scriptural basis just pure experience based(though i vaguely remembered it was heavily detailed account....)